# Regarding wireless lan messaging system

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

i am developing a chat application for local environment where our office employees can chat easily so here I am getting some conflicts when I am trying to send message over the IP but there IP being change dynamically so how can i resolve it .

Comment: Have a central server with a static IP (or at least a domain name). You're not trying to directly connect to another employee's PC, are you? That just won't work.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Set up a local [Jabber](https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend using a well established solution like a local Jabber Server installation and using a client that supports the required features.

If you really want to pull this off on your own, you'll need at least a central controlling point (Server) to abstract Users from their Endpoint.
Configured user would then have to login to that server to signal they are ready to receive messages. Doing this, you have the momentarily correct IP that you can then use to relay messages or to give to other clients wanting to send to that user. Also consider that users may want to use more than one client (they have 2 PCs?). You probably wouldn't want to bind one user to one client device.

Also note that you will have to create a decent protocol for all this. This can be quite tedious if you want similar features to for example Skype Chat or ICQ,  or some derivate of XMPP / Jabber.

This leads me again back to my first suggestion: Better use something that already exists. Installing and configuration of that can already be effort enough. Coding all that by yourself, though will take **way** more effort.

And I didn't even go into status/statusmessages, groupchats, sending/sharing Files, sending messages while User is away/offline ...